# Creating a center-aligned thumbnail from image

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a site with images on it, but I don't want to have the traditional thumbnail (where it's just a smaller image), I want something like this: http://imgur.com/r/funny

Notice how all the images' thumbnails are 160x160 and only shows the center of the image. I'd like to do something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

First, in PHP you use the gd-lib for such things.

The task goes this way:

- Open the original-image with imagecreatefromXXXX: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
- Get the image-boundaries with imagesx() and imagesy()
- The way you want to resize the images is: "Get the smaller side of the original-image and resize the image proportional. So, that at lease one side matches the corresponding resulting image's side". The ticky thing here is, when you have an targeted size, where horizontal- and vertical size are not equal. eg. 170x120.
- Then you create a new image and resize/copy the original image with imagecopyresampled() into that.
- You have now an image where one side is equal to the respective target side. The other side is bigger or has the same size as its corresponding size on the target image. The next step is to crop this image. This can also be done with imagecopyresampled() - also in the same step, were you resized the image.
- Now save the image under a new filename (or in another directory) and link it...